Calculating symbolic softmax expression in sympy
I am new to using sympy. Here I am trying to produce the expression for the softmax of a vector in sympy. I am doing the following:
import sympy as sp

# vector
x = sp.MatrixSymbol('x', p, 1)

# take the elementwise exponential
exp_x = x.applyfunc(sp.exp)

# take the sum across elements
sum_x = sp.Sum(exp_x[j,:], (j, 1, n))

The code above works as expected, however, I get a strange NotImplemented error when I try to divide exp_x by sum_x to obtain the softmax result.
NotImplementedError: noncommutative scalars in MatMul are not supported.
Notably if I try to divide exp_x by any other scalar symbol, the error doesnt show up. For example, exp_x/Symbol('c') does not throw an error. Is this a bug or a feature? What is the workaround?
